# new lines, trouble with printing in console

Tags: python, printing

```
loading = 'LOADING...'
for i in range(10):
    print(loading[i], sep=' ', end=' ', flush=True); sleep(0.5)
```

I don't know how to add a new line after this, for example, psuedo code:

```
loading = 'LOADING...'
for i in range(10):
    print(loading[i], sep=' ', end=' ', flush=True); sleep(0.5)

print("stuff I want to print")
```

when I simply do this, it just prints it on the same line, which I don't want. what would I do instead of this?

Comment: You're using `' '` as the separator; use `\n` instead (either in the `print` call in the inner loop or before the `print` call outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Insert `\n` before next print statement.

```
print("\nstuff I want to print")


L O A D I N G . . . 
stuff I want to print
```

Comment: oh thank you, I was really confused on how that was used